# When hosting Codeigniter 3 Application on iis 8.5 server only loading default Controller index function

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter-3, iis-8.5

I'm setting up a new codeigniter 3 application on IIS 8.5 Server. while loading default controller and index function working fine but after calling any other function it just reloading default controller index function.

This is my Web Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php"/>
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <handlers>
            <add name="PHP-phtml" path="*.phtml" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP70\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" />
            <add name="PHP-php3" path="*.php3" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP70\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" />
            <add name="PHP-php" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP70\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="File" />
        </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Controller

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
$this->load->view('employee_login');
}

public function emp_login_check() {
print_r("hello");
}
}
```

Login is my default controller. The employee_login page loading fine and from employee_login page when i try to call emp_login_check, it's just reloading employee_login page again.

employee_login page

```
<html>
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('Login/emp_login_check'); ?>" method="post">

<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Can any help me, why is not calling emp_login_check function?
Iam new to iis server.

[image: Scrren shot of Browser after clicking Login button]

[image: Site binding (Just i mention in one table)]

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what is your site bindings and site configuration settings.

site bindings:

[image]

controller: Login.php

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('employee_login');
    }
    public function emp_login_check() 
    {
        print_r("hello");
        exit;
    }
}
```

View: employee_login.php

```
 <html>
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="<?php echo base_url('Login/emp_login_check'); ?>" method="post">

<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</html>
```

Config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8066/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

URL rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="RuleRemoveIndex" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already i have Host name something like abc.abctechnologies.com so i require to mention base url like abc.abctechnologies.com:8086? And i checked site binding, type showing https and  port 443. still not getting call in emp_login_check. it's worked fine in Apache server(xampp). I really need your help, i am new to iis server.

Comment: could you please share iis site binding snapshot and browser page when you try to acess emp_login_check?

Comment: if you are using domain name than just enter domain name in base url.

Comment: Added screenshot of browser and binding i mentioned in one table. browser screen shot address showing emp_login_check function after clicking Login button, but it's loading the same employee_login page.

Comment: when am removing handler from web config  am getting error ''HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable''.    <handlers>...... etc.. </handlers>

Comment: Finally i got it. In web config handlers modules="CgiModule", I changed cgiModules to FastCgiModules then it worked fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can post your answer and mark that post. it will help other people who face this issue.